# How can i generate a dropbox api access token that doesnt expire?

Tags: access-token, dropbox-api

Is it possible to generate an access token for DropBox API access that does not expire?

By happenstance I discovered that the generated access token lasts only a few hours and is intended for developer testing only.

I would like to obtain an access token (long or short-lived) **without** presenting the user with a confirmation page followed by a redirect.

Can this be achieved?

**Update**
So far i am seeing that this is not possible.
https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/C-Get-Access-Token-without-browser-interaction/td-p/622443

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox does not offer a way to fully automate this process. The user needs to manually authorize the app at least once.

Note that Dropbox is no longer offering the option for creating new long-lived access tokens. Dropbox is now issuing short-lived access tokens (and optional refresh tokens) instead of long-lived access tokens. You can find [more information on this migration here](https://dropbox.tech/developers/migrating-app-permissions-and-access-tokens#updating-access-token-type).

Apps can still get long-term access by requesting "offline" access though, in which case the app receives a "refresh token" that can be used to retrieve new short-lived access tokens as needed, without further manual user intervention. Refresh tokens do not expire automatically and can be used repeatedly, so you would not need to manually reauthorize the app each time. You can find more information in the [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization). There's a basic outline of processing this flow in [this blog post](https://dropbox.tech/developers/using-oauth-2-0-with-offline-access) which may serve as a useful example.

Comment: Thanks Greg. So to summarize my understanding, i MUST request for authorization once, and there's no way around that? So how can an application that does not have front-end for the user to confirm authorization work?

Comment: Also, im looking what value options do i have for the <STATE> parameter when constructing a request for /oauth2/authorize  ?

Comment: Yes, the app needs to receive authorization from the user in order to be able to access that user's account. This only needs to be done once. (Note though that the authorization can be revoked at any time.) The app will need to have some way of interacting with the user to initially get that authorization, but after that it can operate on its own without a user interface.

Comment: You can find information on how the `state` parameter can be used in [the /oauth2/authorize documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize). There isn't a specific set of values you need to pick from; you can specify arbitrary data.